# Does switching from a J1 visa to TD status prevent you from entering the US for two years?

Tags: usa, visa, canada, canadian-citizens, j-visa

I am currently living in the US on a TN status while my financé is still living in Canada. We are both Canadian citizens. She is looking at taking an internship in the US that would grant her a J-1 visa. But looking into it, it looks like after the J-1 visa expires she is required to leave the US and not return for two years.

Is this really the case for Canadian citizens? When she gets a TD status, will she still be required to remain outside the US until that two-year period has passed?

Comment: She might check into whether she could get a [waiver of the 2 year requirement](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/study-exchange/student/residency-waiver/eligibility.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 2-year requirement in INA 212(e) only applies to immigrant visas and H and L nonimmigrant visas. It does not apply to TN and TD.

The Foreign Affairs Manual explicitly confirms this for TN/TD in [9 FAM 402.17-11](https://fam.state.gov/FAM/09FAM/09FAM040217.html#M402_17_11).

Comment: Cool, this sounds like it also doesn't apply to a B2 visitor's visa. Thanks!